# Updating NPM Requires New Version of NPM(deadlock) With engines Requirement in package.json

Tags: node.js, npm, version-control, package.json, .npmrc

When requiring a strict version of `npm` in `package.json` with an `.npmrc` file it gives an error when running `npm ci` as expected, but does not allow the `npm` version to be updated.

package.json

```
"engines": {
    "npm": "8.7.0"
}
```

.npmrc

```
engine-strict=true
```

error (expected)

```
$ npm ci
npm ERR! code EBADENGINE
npm ERR! engine Unsupported engine
npm ERR! engine Not compatible with your version of node/npm: psw-portal@1.0.0
npm ERR! notsup Not compatible with your version of node/npm: psw-portal@1.0.0
npm ERR! notsup Required: {"npm":"8.8.0"}
npm ERR! notsup Actual:   {"npm":"8.7.0"}
```

error when attempting to update npm (unexpected)

```
$npm install npm@8.8.0
npm ERR! code EBADENGINE
npm ERR! engine Unsupported engine
npm ERR! engine Not compatible with your version of node/npm: psw-portal@1.0.0
npm ERR! notsup Not compatible with your version of node/npm: psw-portal@1.0.0
npm ERR! notsup Required: {"npm":"8.8.0"}
npm ERR! notsup Actual:   {"npm":"8.7.0"}
```

When updating the `npm` version with `npm install npm@8.8.0` the same error is thrown. Installing the new versions requires the new version, resulting in a deadlock...

What would be the appropriate way of enforcing an `npm` version in an Node.js project without this deadlock?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eventually it turned out `npm` could only be updated globally, thus using `npm install -g npm@8.8.0`, instead of `npm install npm@8.8.0`

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just remove deadlock by removing `.npmrc` file or

```js
"engines": {
    "npm": "8.7.0"
}
```

then install your desired npm package
then bring your changes back.
also you can use [nvm](https://learn2torials.com/a/how-to-install-nvm) for better and also backward version changes